# How to set assign row in Excel to Column name in Datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I read data from excel into datagridview in C#. I want to assign row in excel (example 10) to Column Name in datagridview. Code below default get first row in excel.

```
using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    string selectString = @"Select * from [" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "]";
    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand(selectString, connExcel))
    {
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        adp.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do (that it doesn't already do)?

Comment: Yes, it works but instead of first row in excel i want to assign row 10 become column name in datagridview.

Comment: So you want to ignore rows 1-9 completely and just use row 10 and below?

Comment: @mjwills No, I need use all data(but i can delete first row after replace).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it programmatically. In your code, the `adp.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);` is implicitly pulling the column names from the spreadsheet, but not the data. You follow it with `adp.Fill(dt);` which does the same thing with the data.

To do it programmatically, you need to read row 10 using a OleDbDataReader.Get() and assign each Excel cell to the DataGridView column header that matches.

```
DataRow newRow = dt.New
newRow[1] = dr.xxx
newRow[2] = dr.xxx
newRow[3] = dr.xxx
newRow[4] = dr.xxx
newRow[5] = dr.xxx
newRow[6] = dr.xxx
newRow[7] = dr.xxx
newRow[8] = dr.xxx

dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

You will then need to do the rest of the rows of data the same way in a loop. A link to an article that is more specific is [Populate a DGV from a DR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20733/How-to-Populate-a-DataGridView-Control-using-OleDb/). The bottom half covers what you need to do.